# Fix broken permissions on /var (or any other system directory)

Tags: debian, permissions, system-recovery

Long story short, I destroyed `/var` and restored it from backup - but the backup didn't have correct permissions set, and now everything in `/var` is owned by root. This seems to make a few programs unhappy.

I've since fixed apt failing fopen on `/var/cache/man` as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716426/cant-apt-get-remove-or-apt-get-install-fopen-permission-denied) as well as apache2 failing to start (by giving ownership of `/var/lib/apache2` to `www-data`). However, right now the only way to fix everything seems to be to manually muck around with permissions as problems arise - this seems very difficult as I would have to wait for a program to start giving problems, establish that the problem is related to permissions of some files in `/var` and then set them right myself.

Is there an easy way to correct this? I already tried reinstalling (plain `aptitude reinstall x`) every package that was listed in `dpkg -S /var`, but that didn't work.

Comment: The `/var` should be root owned and the permissions should be `755` on the directory. I believe that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually `apt-get --reinstall install package` should work, with files at least:

```
➜  ~  ls -l /usr/share/lintian/checks/version-substvars.desc        
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2441 Jun 22 14:19 /usr/share/lintian/checks/version-substvars.desc
➜  ~  sudo chmod +x /usr/share/lintian/checks/version-substvars.desc
➜  ~  ls -l /usr/share/lintian/checks/version-substvars.desc        
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2441 Jun 22 14:19 /usr/share/lintian/checks/version-substvars.desc
➜  ~  sudo apt-get --reinstall install lintian  
(Reading database ... 291736 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../lintian_2.5.27_all.deb ...
Unpacking lintian (2.5.27) over (2.5.27) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up lintian (2.5.27) ...
➜  ~  ls -l /usr/share/lintian/checks/version-substvars.desc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2441 Jun 22 14:19 /usr/share/lintian/checks/version-substvars.desc
```

Now, you probably didn't get all the packages that have files on your `/var` directory, so its better to *find them all*:

```
➜  ~ find /var -exec dpkg -S {} + 2> /dev/null | grep -v "no path found" | wc -l 
460
```

In my case, it accounts for 460 paths that have a package, this is actually less if you consider that the same package can have several paths, which with some post processing we can find out that are ~122:

```
➜  ~  find /var -exec dpkg -S {} + 2> /dev/null | grep -v "no path found" | cut -d : -f 1 | sort | uniq | wc -l
122
```

This of course counts several package that has the same path, like `wamerican, aspell-en, ispanish, wspanish, aspell-es, myspell-es`. This is easily fixable:

```
➜  ~  find /var -exec dpkg -S {} + 2> /dev/null | grep -v "no path found" | cut -d : -f 1 | sed 's/, /\n/g' | sort | uniq | wc -l
107
```

So, I have 107 package that have any kind of file in `/var` or subdirectories. You can reinstall them using:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install $(find /var -exec dpkg -S {} + 2> /dev/null | grep -v "no path found" | cut -d : -f 1 | sed 's/, /\n/g')
```

This should fix the permissions.

Now, there's another option, find a good installation and copy the file permissions over your installation with:

```
chmod --recursive --reference good/var bad/var
```

Comment: Appreciated esp. the last bit which works on most if not all unixes: *Find a good installation and copy the file permissions over your installation with chmod*

Answer (score 1):

I just saw that this question has been treated brilliantly on this blog:

https://matoski.com/article/debian-restore-var-ownership-permissions/ ([archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20210716045723/https://matoski.com/article/debian-restore-var-ownership-permissions/))

Summary:

Method 1: Virtual Machine

Method 2: From the debian packages

Method 3: Reinstalling with aptitude

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [link-only answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) are discouraged, as the link may become invalid or the linked content change. Please edit your answer to include at least a summary of the linked explanation.