# Setting mode of /var to 777 causes system to no longer boot

Tags: debian, boot-loader

I executed `chmod -R 777 .` command in `/var` directory mistakenly when I tried to execute it in another directory. Now as I start my OS, on the startup page, it crashes and doesn't show the login screen.

How can I correct his?

OS: Debian 10. DE: gnome

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156568/fix-broken-permissions-on-var-or-any-other-system-directory)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reinstall all the packages using aptitude, although this is a quite slow process, but if you want to you can do like so:

```
dpkg --get-selections \* | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -l1 aptitude reinstall
```

You'll have to switch to a console first if the graphical environment is not working.